# Firebase Realtime Database will not update after waking from Doze mode on Android 6.0

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I've been working on an Android app that pulls data from a Firebase Realtime Database and fills a RecyclerView with information. It updates just as it should until the device goes into doze mode. When it wakes from Doze mode, the information does not reload. I have to force close the app and re-open it to get the latest information since the device went in Doze mode.

I've added in a "pull to refresh" with various attempts to force reload the data but it seems to just pull from the (outdated) cache on the device that Firebase makes.

Here is the function I use in a fragment to load the information from Firebase

```
public void loadTweetsFromFirebase() {

    FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    DatabaseReference tweetsRef = database.getReference("rumourTweets");
    Query query = tweetsRef.limitToFirst(100).orderByChild("timestamp");

    query.keepSynced(true);

    if (listener != null) {
        tweetsRef.removeEventListener(listener);
    }
    tweets.clear();
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    listener = query.addValueEventListener(
                new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        for (DataSnapshot obj:
                                dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                            Tweet tweet = obj.getValue(Tweet.class);

                            // The keys are the tweet ids for the initial tweet, so we need to re-construct one with the obj key as the tweet id
                            Tweet newTweet = new Tweet(tweet.getCategory(), tweet.getProfileImgURL(), tweet.getTagName(), tweet.getText(), tweet.getTimestamp(), tweet.getUserId(), tweet.getUserName(), obj.getKey(), tweet.getRetweetedTweet(), tweet.getQuotedTweet());
                            tweets.add(newTweet);
                            adapter.notifyItemInserted(tweets.indexOf(newTweet));
                        }
                        refreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
                        progressBarLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                        Log.w("FB", "getUser:onCancelled", databaseError.toException());
                    }
                });
}
```

Comment: Is there a need to leave the listener active when the app is in the background (not visible)?  You can avoid the Doze mode issue by changing your design to add the listener in `Fragment` lifecycle method `onStart()` and then remove it in `onStop()'.

Comment: No, there is no particular reason to leave it active when the app is not active. It can just update when the user opens the app again. I'll give your suggestion a try! Thanks Frank.